# mongodb: moving field to new document and update fields and array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

```
Collection.find({ $and: [ {title: { $exists: true}}, {reference: { $exists: true }} ]}).pretty()
```

This give me some documents with the structure:

```
{
    "_id" : "EJBFtZ7EeGbBPwJaw",
    "title" : "title",
    "reference" : "8uujF9pivpGA37oQc",
    "parent" : "v7DJzq859XX4kvKPi",
    "ancestors" : [
        "v7DJzq859XX4kvKPi"
    ]
}
```

Now I have to transform all documents in the way:

1. move the title to a new document and
2. update the `parent` id to the new document
3. push the new id to the ancestors (in first position!)

The result should be:

```
{
    "_id" : "gzRn4nDKfeewb8EYE",    // new document
    "title" : "title",              // moved title
    "parent" : "v7DJzq859XX4kvKPi",
    "ancestors" : [
        "v7DJzq859XX4kvKPi"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "EJBFtZ7EeGbBPwJaw",    // removed title
    "reference" : "8uujF9pivpGA37oQc",
    "parent" : "gzRn4nDKfeewb8EYE", // update parent id to new id
    "ancestors" : [
        "gzRn4nDKfeewb8EYE",        // add new id at first pos
        "v7DJzq859XX4kvKPi"
    ]
}
```

So what I'm thinking of is something like that:

```
Collection.find({ $and: [ {title: { $exists: true}}, {reference: { $exists: true }} ]}).forEach(function(doc) {
    // get data from source
    var id     = doc.id;
    var title  = doc.title;
    var parent = doc.parent;

    // insert new document
    var newId = Collection.insert({
        title: title,
        parent: parent,
        ancestors: [parent]
    });

    // update source document
    if (newId) {
        Collection.update(
            { _id: id },
            { 
                $set:   { parent: newId },   // update parent id
                $push:  { ancestors: newId } // update ancestors array
                $unset: { title: '' }        // remove title
            }
        );      
    }

});
```

1. But doing a `$push` will append the id instead of prepending it.
2. Is it correct to use `if (newId) {}` or should I put this part in a callback function of the `insert`?

If there are any improvements possible, please let me know.

Comment: you should specify "$position:0" in push to prepend check following link:-https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update/position/

Comment: Do i have to use `$each` if I use `$position`, although there is only one element I want to push?

Comment: yeah you need to use each try using $push:  { ancestors: {$each:[newId], $position:0}

Answer (score 1):

1) Try $position variable https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/position/#up._S_position

2) Personally I would do the same as the MongoDB insert method return the new _ID created.

Regards